# Install Radeon HD 6450 driver in 18.04

Tags: radeon

I am looking to see if I can solve an issue with installing different graphics card drivers.  I am using 18.04 with a Radeon HD6450 (quite old hardware) I can see drivers for these but they are for older versions of Ubuntu.

https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/amd-radeon-hd/amd-radeon-hd-6000-series/amd-radeon-hd-6450

Will they cause an issue if I try and install on a later version than specified?

Thanks

Comment: This driver won't work.

Comment: Thank you, I will try and work out which drivers are being used when I get home.